# what's the best way to secure rest web services using spring?

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, ws-security

What is the Best way to secure REST Services (develop by Spring Framework) for use in Android app? Please consider the limitation of httpclient in android. using http authentication header is enough?
My need is to be able to control which application is calling my web service and is this application authorized to call it.

Comment: Consider using [Spring Security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/)

Comment: Can you give an example ?

Comment: There are plenty of them in the shared link.

Comment: Most of them about form-based login with spring security